# How servlet request object is allocated to thread and returns response object

Tags: http, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, web-container

I’m trying to understand how webcontainer work for the http request and sent back response and I’m stuck in middle

1. Clients submits a http request
2. Web server receives the http request and hand over to webcontainer
3. Webcontainer converts the http request to ServletRequest object and empty ServletResponse object
4. Webcontainer will allocate one thread from thread pool per request

I got stuck here
The thread will call service(req,res)inside the run method of thread and service method’s return type is void. The service method will call dopost or doget method based on the client submitted. How the thread will get the response object back which was constructed from void doGet(req,res).

Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-json-response this will help you to understand.

Comment: DoGet/doPost receive the reesponse object and there you can write on the response's output stream or do some forward or whatelse you need. There is no *back* to the thread, the response is the same created before the doPost call.